# battery used for 1% of cpu usage

Tags: android, cpu-usage, battery

A application is using 1% of cpu(I got cpu usage by 'top' command). I want to calculate how much battery needed to provide this 1% of cpu usage. i.e   `battery_usage_by_app = cpu_usage (operater) operation_to_do`. I am considering battery used for cpu operation. So can any one tel me how can I get battery used for 1% of cpu usage.